# CLANG/LLVM Escape analysis for C variables

Tags: c, clang, llvm, analysis, escape-analysis

I would like to do escape analysis using clang.
What my code does is parsing a C code and extracting all variables statements and so on.
Is there a simple way to find out if my local variables escape? Or do I have to do all by hand?

Comment: You can automate as much of this as you like.  Clang is a good foundation.  What's your question?

Comment: He asks for an easy way to do this, presumably something like a method varDecl->mayEscape().

Comment: @matg did you find any?

Comment: not really - did it myself

Comment: Do you have a link to your code?